# Devise after user login create action with table relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

After User login with devise_token_auth then create operation_system name with "android" or "ios" so what should I do? Here is my code:

```
class CreateOperatingSystems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :operating_systems do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class DeviseTokenAuthCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
       .......................
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What's the relation between OS and user? User has many OS? Do you want to create a new one every time the user logs in? What happen if they log in in Android, and then in IOS?

Comment: so we will track every user login